# appending to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python code like this:

```
experiment_str = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
conversation_dict = dict.fromkeys(experiment_str,[])
conversation_dict['0'].append(10)
```

I want to add `10` to only the first key but it adds to *all keys*. Can you please help me to understand it?

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For a dictionary you shouldn't be using the .append method, simply use '=':

```
conversation_dict['0'] = 10
```

as well as this, if you want to create a new key, use the same method.